# My life will be treating me

Tags: sentence-choice

Which one sounds the most natural?

1. Is this really gonna be the way my life treats me?
2. Is this really gonna be the way my life will be treating me?
3. Is this really gonna be how my life will be treating me?
4. Is this really gonna be how my life treats me?

Comment: "Gonna" is slang. It should be "going to" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Each of these is acceptable and reasonably natural. However corresponding forms with "the way life treats me" or "the way life will be treating me" are more common, and to me seem more natural, than the forms with "my life" [A Googlr ngrams plot](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=way+life+treats%2Cway+my+life+treats+&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cway%20life%20treats%3B%2Cc0) seems to confirm this.

The forms with "will be treating" are discussing what happens in the future, while the forms with "treats" may be discussing the past, or the past through the future. That is a difference in meaning which may oir may not be significant, depending on the larger context.

Answer (score -1):

> Q. **I have no idea which one sounds the most natural**

> Is this really gonna be the way my life treats me?

> Is this really gonna be the way my life will be treating me?

> Is this really gonna be how my life will be treating me?

> Is this really gonna be how my life treats me?

---

A. I would suggest that **none of them sound natural**.

Firstly **life is singular and you are using the plural form of Treat**. Secondly The associations with life. In the phrases **you are alluding to an entity "life" which is outside of your control** and which has an impact on your own personal life. However you are **naming the entity "my life**" which then presumably **impacts on "my life"**? Therefore we should **name the entity "life"**.

Try these.

> Is this really gonna be the way my life treats me?

**Is this really going to be the way life will treat me?**

> Is this really gonna be the way my life will be treating me?

**Is this really, the way my life will be?**

> Is this really gonna be how my life will be treating me?

**Is this really going to be how life will treat me?**

> Is this really gonna be how my life treats me?

**Is this really going to be how my life will be?**

---

> **treat verb** (DEAL WITH) to behave towards someone or deal with something in a particular way Ref CED [Treat](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/treat?q=treats)

Comment: Don't quote the entire question. Especially, don't do it twice.

Comment: I quote the questions because people keep editing them. Then your answer becomes meaningless. I have also had people come along after the edit and mark me down for not answering the question. The following is an example of a change albeit one made in a nice way. Praise be to the "Questioner" he has acknowledged the change and left the original Usually they do not.https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/220723/can-the-structure-somebody-doing-replace-a-clause/220727#220727

Comment: Also questioner's have a habit of lists and variations, such that you are often giving as many as 8 to 10 explanations, so I quote the original text next to the explanation.

Comment: I have been through all the you are wrong and the questioner cannot do that but really !!! You have to tell the dog not to wag its tail. Talking to the tail gets you nowhere. Funnily enough some of the people who edit questions also criticise people for posting the questions.