# Can the structure "somebody doing" replace a clause?

Tags: grammar, infinitives

Consider the situation. A soldier returns home safe and sound from war. And his mother says

> It is such a blessing for him to come back safe!

It is grammatically correct to change this to

> Him coming back safe is such a blessing!

---

**update:** I apologize if I gave a bad example to describe the question. An answer pointed out that this is more of a matter of meaning than of grammar. However, that is not what I had intended to ask. Hopefully this new example will sound better.

> It is unacceptable for this information to be leaked.

It is grammatical to change it to

> This information getting leaked is unacceptable.

Comment: "getting leaked" I would suggest this is another incorrect sentence. The C.I.A. has a leak, not the information. The information is leaked or not not leaked. The ink is dry or not dry. The activity of a vessel leaking water is an ongoing event. However do we relate the information in your example to the vessel or the water?

Answer (score 1):

**Can the structure “sb doing” replace a clause?**
**It is grammatically correct to change this to**

I suggest that your question is not correct, once again the question is about grammar whilst disregarding meaning or use. "**Such**" is a word used to emphasis things. So what is the important thing in this sentence? The Blessing or that he has come home safe? I would suggest that the original sentence emphasis both whilst the second does not and also alters the meaning. Lets show this by substituting the meaning of Blessing  for it's meaning (something that is extremely lucky or makes you happy) in the sentences

**It is such luck/happiness for him to come back safe** He is very lucky/happy **to have been able to come back**

**Him coming back safe is such luck/happy** His coming back brings a lot of **luck/happiness because he is back**

So the "whether the grammar may be correct" or not is in my opinion a little irrelevant. The use and therefore meaning should be the more important factor.

> **Blessing** noun (LUCKY SITUATION) [Cambridge English dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blessing) something that is extremely lucky or makes you happy:

P.S. I would also suggest that the use of blessing is wrong in both sentences as I believe that it is trying to imply that the mothers prayers have been answered rather than the luck involved with her son's return.

---

### The Question examples have Changed.

Q. Can the structure “sb doing” replace a clause? It is grammatically correct to change this to

I suggest that your question is not correct, once again the question is about grammar whilst disregarding meaning or use. "unacceptable" is a word used to describe something that is not acceptable. So what is the important thing in this sentence? The acceptability of the action or what has/is actually happened/happening? I would suggest that the original sentence and the alternative **are not describing what events are taking place.**

*A swimming pool has a leak, the sauce bottle is leaking. The "White House" has a leak. The water, ketchup, information comes out.*

**So the "whether the grammar may be correct" or not is in my opinion a little irrelevant. The use and therefore meaning should be the more important factor.**